Motion from COM frame
If there’s a spring block system consisting of 2 blocks, say A and B, and there is an external force F acting on block A in right wards direction and if we now analyze the motion from COM Frame, the net force on the system comes out to be zero. Why is this always true from the COM Frame?

It's not true.  But I can guess how you got there.
In the COM frame, if there is an external force acting on block A, there is an external force acting on block A.  The force doesn't vanish.
However, if you attempt to apply F=ma, it may appear as if the force must vanish, as the acceleration in the COM frame must, by necessity, be 0.
The trick is that F=ma only applies in inertial frames.  Your COM frame is an accelerating frame, which has a slightly different equation of motion.  This is similar to what you will find when you work in rotating frames, where we see "pseudoforces" which are actually acceleration terms that must be added to ensure that the physics in that rotating frame is "the same" as applying F=ma in an inertial frame.

Actually I am asking why the net force on the whole SYSTEM comes out to be zero from COM frame, not the individual block A

Can you explain?  The net force on the system should not be 0.  That isn't so much a calculated thing as "there is 1 external force on the system, so the force on the system is simply that force"  If there's a 10N force on block A, there is a 10N force on the system.  And since it is the only external force, there is a net force of 10N

If we calculate the net force acting on both blocks in the frame of COM, the net force on system comes out to be 0. This is what I’m confused about

can you show me how you get to that conclusion?  The net force on both blocks in the COM frame is not zero, because there is an external force. I think it is the finding of the net force which is giving you trouble. I'd recommend editing the question to show your work calculating the net force. Then we can help you with that.  Perhaps scan in a picture of the free body diagram you did.

this is the COM equation
$$ R_c=\frac{m_A\,r_A+m_B\,r_B}{m_A+m_B}$$
from here the COM acceleration
$$ a_c=\frac{m_A\,a_A+m_B\,a_B}{m_A+m_B}$$
with $~m_A\,a_A=F+F_K\quad,m_B\,a_B=-F_K$
where $~,F_K~$ is the spring force
you obtain
$$(m_A+m_B)\,a_c=F $$
thus the external force F , is still there

I know that the force is still there but I’m asking if we draw the FBD of blocks in the FRAME OF COM, the net force comes out to be 0 on the system
